# Unable to implement print preview in javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, django

I am trying to implement the print preview on a page that opens as pdf format.However, when the page opens , the print function is not executed and nothing happens. What could I be doing wrong? I am using Python with Django and I want to implement the print function using javascript.

Comment: Did you ever get to solve you issue?

Answer (score 1):

Try function assignment without executing the function (without parathesis).

```
window.onload = funcloadprint;
```

And maybe put the assigment after the declaration, not before.

---

**A little suggestion**

It is good practice to wrap your javascript code in a [closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work) to avoid global namespace polution. Its not necessary for this small case, but it would be good for your future projects to read up about it.

```
(function() {
    function funcloadprint() {
        ...
    };
    window.onload = funcloadprint;
})();
```

Comment: Did this help you? Could you get it working? If so, I would appreciate if you marked the answer as accepted.